# Обновление кластера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Имеется кластер с макетом в виде круговой диаграммы и собственное изображение меток. Как организовать изменение цвета кластера при изменении переменной без изменения зума?

Изображение меняю так:

```
geoObjects[j].options.set({iconImageHref: '1.png', iconColor: '#930005',});
geoObjects[j].options.set({iconImageHref: '2.png', iconColor: '#00bf0d',});
```

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант, это удалить кластеризатор и добавить его заново.

```
geoObjects[0].options.set("iconColor", '#930005');
myMap.geoObjects.remove(clusterer);
myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ke7xjozb/